# Expresión regular para cadena con más de un carácter y que no tenga "b"

Tags: java, regex

necesito hacer una función que determine si una cadena tiene más de un carácter y que no haya "b" en ella.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? He probado esto:

```
public static boolean moreOneCharacterButB(String string) {

    return string.matches(".{2,}&&^b");
}
```

Quizás estoy probando una burrada, pero no me entero muy bien de cómo va el tema de las expresiones regulares.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que una cadena tenga al menos dos caracteres y que todos ellos sean diferentes a "b" se puede expresar como:

```
^[^b]{2,}$
```

Donde `^` indica principio, `$` final y `[^b]{2,}` "cualquier cosa menos `b`" 2 o más veces.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Hay una cosa que no entiendo, y es ¿por qué pones el carácter de inicio y final? ¿Es por convención? O tiene alguna utilidad. Lo he probado sin ellos y funcionan igual, ¿no?

Gracias!

Comment: Sin `^` y `$` la expresión haría match con algo como `aaab` puesto que `aaa` tiene al menos dos caracteres que no son `b`, si los incluyes ya no haría match. Nota que algunas funciones como `re.fullmatch` en python actúan como si incluyeras `^$`.

Comment: @Manuel qué bien que funcione! Usamos `^` y `$` para indicar principio y final de palabra para fijar la cadena exactamente. Según cómo se escriba una expresión, podría darse la situación que "aaab" te funciona, porque existen dos letras diferentes de "b" seguidas... pero la "b" está al final. Indicando principio y final evitamos problemas de estos.

Comment: @OscarDavidArbeláez caramba, escribimos lo mismo :) Mil gracias por comentar y explicar tan bien.